# dnvm upgrade permission denied

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

I try to update dnvm in my Mac (El Capitán) but I always has this error:

```
dnvm upgrade
Determining latest version
Latest version is 1.0.0-rc1-update1 
dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1 already installed in /usr/local/lib/dnx
Adding /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin to process PATH
Updating alias 'default' to 'dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1'
-bash: /Users/chemitaxis/.dnx/alias/default.alias: Permission denied
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What are the file perms on `default.alias`?

Comment: How can I check it? Thanks! @SushiHangover

Comment: "ls -l /Users/chemitaxis/.dnx/alias/default.alias"

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover -rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  39 28 nov 19:25 /Users/chemitaxis/.dnx/alias/default.alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you used the installer that had a bug in it (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3191#issuecomment-159073517)) and now your `.dnx` folder has the wrong permissions.

You have two options:

1. Delete the `/usr/local/lib/dnx` and `/Users/chemitaxis/.dnx` folders, then get the latest installer and reinstall.
2. If you don't want to delete those folders, here's a workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3191#issuecomment-159073517

Comment: Ok, solved and all works fine, do i need repeat this process everytime? Thanks!! @Victor-Hurdugaci

Comment: Nope. It should be a one time thing